# list returns None, omits value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am attempting to return values and positions of letters. Running this as a plain for loop works just fine. It's when I turned it into a function that it started to look wonky.

Here it is along with its output:

```
dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2 ... 'z': 26}

list1 = []
list2 = []

def plot(word):
    counter = 0
    for i in word:
        y = dict.get(i)
        list1.append(y) #keeps printing None for the first letters
        counter += 1
        x = counter
        list2.append(x)
    print list1
    print list2
    r = zip(list1, list2)
    print r

t = raw_input('Enter word: ')
Enter word: Hello

plot(t)

Output:
[None, None, 5, 12, 12, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[(None, 1), (None, 2), (5, 3), (12, 4), (12, 5)]
```

Comment: If `dict.get(i)` is `None`, then `i` isn't a key in `dict`. `'h'` is in it, but is `'H'`? Also, *don't name your own dictionary `dict`*.

Comment: The output I'm seeking is [(8, 1), (5, 2), (12, 3), (12, 4), (15, 5)]

Comment: Also, notice that list1 has six elements, even though 'Hello' only has five letters. So you're actually only missing one letter. Try using the lower() method on the word to get all letters into lowercase. Then make sure there are no spaces before the word (looks like 'Hello' has a space before it).

Comment: Seems like you're missing some characters in your dictionary. Note that they are case-sensitive. `d.get("foo")` will return `None` if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue is that your are trying to map a capital letter. I would simply change the for loop to iterate over the lowercase.

```
for i in word.lower():
    y = dict.get(i)
    list1.append(y) #keeps printing None for the first letters
    counter += 1
    x = counter
    list2.append(x)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I also found that it was also counting the extra space after the colon in raw_input('Enter word: '). When I removed it, everything went smoothly.